# Safari - IPAD - Disable bounce (no scroll) without -webkit-overflow-scrolling

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, ipad

First i have tested a lot of solution in the web but all solution never work.

I have a webpage with an Iframe and inside this, one `div` with `overflow:hidden` and one `div` with `overflow:scroll`.

When i want scroll into the `div` contain in the `Iframe`, the bounce broken all. The bounce appear after each scroll and the content appear little by little.

I want disable bounce but not the scroll. And i dont want use `-webkit-overflow-scrolling`. because after apply `-webkit-overflow-scrolling`, all the overflow in my page is overflow:auto and is it no good way for me.

I have try this solution but it's no good and disabled scrolling:

```
var xStart, yStart = 0;

document.addEventListener('touchstart',function(e) {
    xStart = e.touches[0].screenX;
    yStart = e.touches[0].screenY;
});

document.addEventListener('touchmove',function(e) {
    var xMovement = Math.abs(e.touches[0].screenX - xStart);
    var yMovement = Math.abs(e.touches[0].screenY - yStart);
    if((yMovement * 3) > xMovement) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

You can view exaclty what i say, please see my page : http://cipa.ch/forStack/

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=640">
 </head>
 <body  style="margin:0;padding:0;">
  <iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" style="margin:0;padding:0;width:100%;height:90%;position:absolute" src="http://cipa.ch/forStack/test.html" >
  </iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you want to disable bouncing effect that by default in safari ?

Comment: see my answer just solve this issue on few days before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try by adding `position:fixed` on body tag

```
body {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok now with your solution the page have a bug. Please try to scroll bottom  a lot of times (the same thing to refresh the page in iphone app) and you can see the content of the page is resized. why? and how resolve this bug. thanks

Comment: can share link again with fix position body  ?

Comment: which browser you are using working fine here in safari 9

Comment: This issue is only on ipad or iphone. I use ipad 8.1.3 version

Comment: have you add this meta tag ? <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108525/discussion-between-ismail-farooq-and-p-frank).